# Query to get the physical file name of the database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query, subquery, syntax

Im trying to get the physical file name of a database, and when i query `sys.database_files`, under the physical file name column, you get the whole path (`ie. S:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\tempdb.mdf` ). How can i dynamically extract just the `tempdb.mdf` off of that string? I was thinking of using `SUBSTRING()` + `CHARINDEX()` but cant figure it out since im new to this. `CHARINDEX()` only searches for a substring from left to right. Is there a function which searches a particular string from right to left? That way i can just search from the last back slash base from my example. Any input would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

@Stringss is a variable to simulate the field you already obtained

```
DECLARE @String NVARCHAR(MAX)='S:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\tempdb.mdf'

SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@String),0,CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(@String),0)))
```